# Why can't you have measurable cardinals in L?

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

When I initially read about this, I thought it must be due to the cardinality of a measurable cardinal being "too high to fit in L". But this is obviously false, because the measurable cardinal exists as an ordinal in L.
So my question then is "Why isn't this ordinal in L recognized as a measurable cardinal ?".
Or equivalently, "What prevents me from constructing a $\kappa$-complete ultrafilter on this ordinal ?"

Request: Please don't repeat the formal proof of the theorem as this is available in standard textbooks.
What I am looking for is something more intuitive, similar to:
Q:"Why are the real numbers uncountable ?"
A:"Because every time you try to construct a bijection from naturals to reals, you can always find a real number which is not in the image of the bijection"

Comment: Intuitive reason: because the measure/$\kappa$-complete ultrafilter is too complex to "fit" in $L$.

Comment: Measurable cardinals imply the existence of elementary embeddings from the universe strictly into itself. This means that the universe is not rigid. It is rather big, in some sense bigger than it needs to be. On the other hand, the Condensation lemma implies the opposite. Namely that $L$ is the least universe of sets, and that it contains the essentials of every universe of sets. Therefore $L$ is very rigid and small.

Comment: Thanks, Martin. Looks like Asaf and you are indicating the same answer - since the measurable cardinal exists as a set in L, identifying which subsets belong to the ultrafilter is "too complex to carry out in L". Would that be a sensible way to put it ?

Comment: @user42761, yes. Asaf gives the exact technical reason.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is the intuition in a nutshell.

If you have a measure, you can take an ultrapower of the universe to define a proper submodel. Why proper? We can show that a measure is never itself an element of the ultrapower it generates. But this would be an inner model smaller than $L$. This is impossible, in part because the ultrapower satisfies $V=L$, and therefore must be $L$.

So the measurable cardinal is itself in $L$, and sure it's inaccessible and even more, when considered in $L$. But its measure(s) are not in $L$. So it is not measurable *in $L$*.

Comment: Just to understand this better: By "measure", do you mean $\kappa$ complete ultrafilter ?  
If so, here's what keeps confusing me. My understanding is, Constructing an ultrafilter on a set simply means going over it's subsets and identifying which ones belong to the ultrafilter and which ones don't.  
Now the measurable cardinal exists as a set in L. So, this means the "subset identification operation" I mentioned always fails. Why would that be ? Is the "definability criterion" used to make L too weak ?

Comment: Why would the ultrafilter construction you describe gives out a $\kappa$ complete ultrafilter?

Comment: (The point to remember about my previous comment is that even on a measurable cardinals there are ultrafilters which are not $\kappa$-complete. So constructing an ultrafilter does not mean that you automatically made it a measurable cardinal. Since in that case, *every* cardinal would be measurable, and all the theorems showing that a measurable cardinal is regular and a strong limit cardinal, well, there would be false.)

Comment: Okay, let me rephrase what I meant.   A $\kappa$ complete ultrafilter (measure) would be an element of P(P($\kappa$)). So my confusion was that since $\kappa$ exists in L (as an ordinal), what prevents the measure from existing ? But I think I see it now. By definition of L, there are strong restrictions on what kind of subsets of a set are "allowed", which means that even if $\kappa$ exists in L, there are restrictions on what elements can exist in P($\kappa$) or P(P($\kappa$)). So that's what prevents the measure existing in L. Is this correct ?

Comment: Well, you sort of getting it backwards. There is no "inherent restriction" in the construction of $L$ which disallows a measurable. But it follows from the fact that a measurable cardinal implies the existence of an inner model which is strictly smaller than the universe, which is itself impossible in $L$. It's just one of these things you need to get used to after some time, I guess. It took more the better part of my masters to get used to the whole large cardinals thing. It's not something one comprehends in a few days without a lot of prior background.

Comment: Thanks for saying that. I started studying reading about large cardinals a couple of months back. I find understanding inaccessible, Mahlo and so on is not too difficult - you just "stretch" the universe upwards by saying "Here's an even bigger jumbo-sized infinity". But at the level of measurables, it was getting very fuzzy - somehow the statements were saying something about the "universe as a whole" rather than throwing in another infinity. It's encouraging to know that this takes time to master.